# Set width of table - not afftected

Tags: css, class, html-table

I am trying to set a fixed width to a certain table with the class selector.
But its not affected at all. What is missing/wrong with this syntax?

**css**

```
.delivoptions_table th {
  table-layout:fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**the table ..**

```
<div class = "delivoptions_table">
    <table id="deliver_alt_table">

            <tr>
                <td> ... </td>
            </tr>

         ...

    </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selector is targeting all `<th>` elements within the `.delivoptions_table` `<div>`, but you don't have any `<th>` elements inside. Update your selector to target the `<table>` itself:

```
.delivoptions_table table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```